# Regex to match only book('knjiga') with specific name('naslov')

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a simple xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book_list>
    <book rbr="1" >
        <title> Yacc </title>
        <author> Filip Maric </author>
        <year> 2004 </year>
        <publisher> Matematicki fakultet </publisher>
        <price currency="din"> 100 </price>
    </book>
    <book rbr="2" >
        <author> Fredrik Lundh </author>
        <price currency="eur"> 50 </price>
        <publisher> O’Reilly & Associates </publisher>
        <year> 2001 </year>
        <title> Python Standard Library </title>
    </book>
</book_list>
```

I need to match a book with a specific name with regex in Python. I can easily match any book with:

`r'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>.*?</book>'`

(single line mode on), and then check if it is the right one, but if I want to match specific book - e.g., Python Standard Library, direct with regex, I can't get it right. If I try

`r'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>(?P<book>.*?<title> Python Standard Library </title>.*?)</book>'`

, with single line mode on, it will match everything from the beginning and I understand why but I couldn't find the way to match only one book tag. I tried all lookups and all different modes without success.

What is the right way to do it, that will work for any number of books in book_list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is greatly complicated by the the fact that the `<title>` tag is not consistently the first child tag under `<book>`. If it were, you could use:

```
m = re.search(r'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>\s*(?P<book><title> Python Standard Library </title>).*?</book>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

That is, replacing `.*?` with `\s*`.

The trick is to make sure that that after you have matched a `<book>` tag that the `<title>` tag you are looking for does not come after a future `</book>` tag. This can be accomplished with a negative lookahead (it's not pretty):

```
import re

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<book_list>
    <book rbr="1" >
        <title> Yacc </title>
        <author> Filip Maric </author>
        <year> 2004 </year>
        <publisher> Matematicki fakultet </publisher>
        <price currency="din"> 100 </price>
    </book>
    <book rbr="2" >
        <author> Fredrik Lundh </author>
        <price currency="eur"> 50 </price>
        <publisher> O’Reilly & Associates </publisher>
        <year> 2001 </year>
        <title> Python Standard Library </title>
    </book>
</book_list>"""

m = re.search(r'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>(?!.*</book>.*<title> Python Standard Library </title>).*(?P<book><title> Python Standard Library </title>).*?</book>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(m.group('book'))
m = re.search(r'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>(?!.*</book>.*<title> Yacc </title>).*(?P<book><title> Yacc </title>).*?</book>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(m.group('book'))
```

Prints:

```
<title> Python Standard Library </title>
<title> Yacc </title>
```

[See demo](https://ideone.com/tF8IXv)

You can reduce the redundancy by using *formatted string literals* if your Python supports them (or the `str.format` method if it doesn't):

```
title = '<title> Python Standard Library </title>'
m = re.search(rf'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>(?!.*</book>.*{title}).*(?P<book>{title}).*?</book>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

**An Alternate Approach**

This approach builds a list of all the individual `<book>` tags and then searches each one in order looking for the title of interest:

```
# create list of <book> ... </book> strings:
books = re.findall(r'<book\s*rbr="\d+"\s*>.*?</book>', xml, flags=re.DOTALL)
title = '<title> Python Standard Library </title>'
# now search each <book>...</book> string looking for the title string:
for book in books:
    if re.search(rf'{title}', book):
        print(title)
        print(book)
```

Prints:

```
<title> Python Standard Library </title>
<book rbr="2" >
        <author> Fredrik Lundh </author>
        <price currency="eur"> 50 </price>
        <publisher> O'Reilly & Associates </publisher>
        <year> 2001 </year>
        <title> Python Standard Library </title>
    </book>
```

Comment: It is pretty enough. I understand why it works but idea is not really straight forward to me yet. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the solution to add an alternate approach that is hopefully more straight forward.

Comment: I solved it that way yesterday, but thanks anyway! I guess I need more theory and practice with regex. You helped me a lot!